# developing Android on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

which eclipse version I should Download to start developing on Android ?
 From This Site :http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Thanks

Comment: you should download "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers"..

Comment: Download "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers". But you will still need to follow step by step guide in [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) in order to start developing for Android.

Comment: Download this one: [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigosr1) Choose the one that fits your operating system on the right.

Comment: "Eclipse for Java" and follow the steps mentioned here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

Comment: you might want to take a look at developers.android.com. All the information is already listed there.

Comment: We do not know your OS, but you should go for "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers". How to install Android SDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) is the Android started guide

Comment: Refer this articles http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html

Comment: "Eclipse Classic" is for you. And your next question will be "which version of android I must to develop?". Here give a decision yourself with this : http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Classic 3.7.1. Anyway, it's already said on Android Developer page anyway: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

> The "Eclipse Classic" version is recommended

Next time please do some little searching before asking, thank you.

Comment: I searched but I want to be sure no more

Comment: Android Developer page should be trusted on such matters.